# How to properly subdivide model for 3d printing?

Tags: geometry, subdivision-surface, 3d-printing

I have this part of a model that doesn't have as much geometry as I want.

[image]

I tried to use Subdivision modifier but I got this instead:

[image]

I want to be able to not see any edges when printing. I'm also open to use any other program if needed.

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GNPmX4Y1jW9vAhlHHp7Z5NrlNbf15Qd7/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: That object appears to be made from tris rather than quads which the subdiv modifier doesn't like. What software was used to create it?

Comment: i dont know. i downloaded it from thingiverse. is there any way to convert it? im fine with doing it manually as well

Comment: Not really, The topology is a complete mess. Starting again from scratch using Blender would be the way to go.

Comment: I honestly can't tell exactly how someone might have modeled something so simple and mad it that big of a mess :P

Comment: i think they ripped it from the game and did minimum fixing. it looks fine when printed its just pretty lowpoly

Comment: Here's a [clean hipoly copy](https://blend-exchange.com/b/KBm7wB51/), trying to use Z-fighting as a guide to accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

It must be modelled in another software. Maybe that's conversion from solid to surface model and that's why the geometry is a mess making it difficult to work with. It will definitely be a lot easier and precise to model it from scratch than to attempt to fix it, but you could go to edit mode(tab), select the edges you want sharp ctrl+clicking to select shortest path and then crease them(shift+e -> 1) to make them sharp during subdivision.

Comment: yeah that diddnt work very well but thanks anyway! i'll just model it from scratch

Comment: Well... What exactly did you expect then? Seems to work pretty well... https://i.imgur.com/KVHJFGN.png